# jquery why .text hide automatically

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, hide

I find it very weird to see that if i display an error on error div on form submit they just disappear straight away

my test code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>TEST</title>
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<form method="post" id="fid" action="#">
    <input type="text"><div id="err"></div>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" name="button" />
</form>


<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
        $('#fid').submit(function(){
            $('#err').text('Hello World');
            //$('#err').html('Hello World');
        });
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

I'm just displaying an error message regardless if user has left the field empty or not just to check once i get this successfully then i would go and implement the full functionality.

**PLEASE NOTE: the error mess appear for less then a second and then disappear automaticlly**

Regards

Comment: Your `$("#fid").submit()` triggers a postback, hence the page is reloaded and your error text disappears since it's only displayed on a postback.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to prevent the form from submitting using preventDefault, or by returning false.

```
$('#fid').submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#err').text('Hello World');
});
```

Remember to add the logic so you only prevent default if an error has occurred, otherwise the form will never submit.

Answer (score 4):

**[e.preventDefault()](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/)**; stop the  form submit action

```
$(function(){
        $('#fid').click(function(e){
           e.preventDefault();
            $('#err').text('Hello World');
            //$('#err').html('Hello World');
        });
    });
```

If this method is called, the default action of the event will not be triggered

Comment: why is this the right answer? Please provide some explanation with your code.

Comment: it seems I cannot do so for some reason.

Comment: @balachandran `pls remove the downvote`, As a techie you should not beg by using words like `please`. Raise your collars and just edit your post then notify him(sevenseacat), he would uncast the downvote..

Answer (score 4):

```
$(function(){
    $('#fid').submit(function(e){
        $('#err').text('Hello World');
        //$('#err').html('Hello World');
        e.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

you need to prevent the form from submitting by using e.preventDefault(); so with in the .submit() method call that e.preventDefault();

Answer (score 3):

```
$(function(){
        $('#fid').submit(function(e){
            $('#err').text('Hello World');
            //$('#err').html('Hello World');
            e.preventDefault();
        });
    });
```

You need to stop form from submission.

Answer (score 2):

What seems to me you want to do some validation then you can do this:

```
$(function(){
    $('#fid').submit(function(e){
       if($.trim($(this).find(':text').val()) == ''){
         $('#err').text('Hello World');
         e.preventDefault();
       }
    });
});
```

---

*the error mess appear for less then a second and then disappear automaticlly*

Its because of default behavior of `form` with attribute `action` defined to submit values to. Even if you do a `#` in the action then the behavior does not stop it submits to the current page.